# Calling Image Files Without Having Their Name In Express.JS

Tags: node.js, express

In `ExpressJS` I want to call up **images**, without having their `path` or `name`.

Maybe scanning a directory on the server side and then sending the path information to the **client**?

The `paths` look like:

```
/images/blocks/trees/random-file-name.png
```

or

```
/images/blocks/grass/random-file-name.png
```

some ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Probably you cannot access the remote directory directly on the front-ent if you don't set it as a static folder. E.g. `app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`. So, if you want to do it randomly I think you would have to at least init all the possible folders to be accessible on the front-end first.

Comment: and how should this be done ?

Comment: Do you have a list of possible folders to be chosen randomly or it is possible anything (something you may not even know)?

Comment: I've got 50 files like `grass-center-3_top.png` or `tree-center-2_bottom.png` in one single folder ... explanation: I am developing a game, and these images are for the game world. thanks.

Comment: maybe something like php's glob() function ?!!

Comment: Is it one folder and random images or is it random images in a single folder?

Comment: isn't it the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133307/discussion-between-tom-and-timo).